# Send a message as a user to another one

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

Is it possible to send messages as a real user (not a page. For example myself) to another user using the Facebook Graph API?

In other words, can I create an app that will make an API call which will send a message as myself to a friend of mine (as if I have sent it myself)

The `send` and `conversation` API seems to be only about sending and receiving messages as a page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is only an API for Page to User communication, but not for User to User communication.